# Magento - disable the customer Dashboard page

Tags: magento

I want to disable the complete customers Dashboard page and redirect customers to homepage after login.

I don't know exactly how can I do that surely because the customers data of my client are always and only from a csv file imported.

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a new modul in: **app/code/local/**

create following directories and files:

**app/code/local/Namespace/Modulname/etc/config.xml**

**app/code/local/Namespace/Modulname/controllers/AccountController.php**

write this in the config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Modulname>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Namespace_Modulname>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <customer>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Namespace_Modulname</module>
                    <frontName>customer</frontName>
                </args>
            </customer>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

write this in the AccountController.php:

```
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Customer').DS.'AccountController.php';

class Namespace_Modulname_AccountController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController
{
    public function loginPostAction()
    {
        parent::loginPostAction();

        if( $session->isLoggedIn() )
        {               
            //redirect after login
            $url = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB);
            $this->_redirectUrl($url);
        } 
    }
}
```

dont forget to activate your new modul:

create a new file in: **app/etc/modules/Namespace.xml**

and insert:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Modulname>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Namespace_ModulName>
        </modules>
</config>
```

Well this is no complete deactivation of the customer area, but you can redirect now every route to the customer dashboard. If there's no other link on your website to the customer dashboard you also can remove all elemtents from the customer dashboard by removing the used blocks in the customer.xml.

Hope this helps.

Danny

Comment: Thanks a lot danny, I have added this because I have a not the variable sesion defined : ´$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));´ it works, but at the end of the order page (order success), when I click om the order number I'm landed in the Order page, with the complte dashboard links in the left column. The page url is : "/sales/order/view/order_id/87/". How can I disable also this page and the other pages like "Address Book".... Thanks :)

Comment: I think you've already answered your question by yourself. Go to `app\code\Mage\Sales\controllers\OrderController.php` there you will find the `viewAction()` function. Just overwrite it like above, add a new router to the **config.xml**, create a new **OrderController.php** and redirect it to where every you like.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the code, works great for me on 1.7.
One small addition which I made is to add a confirmation message, so that the user can see positive feedback that they've actually logged in.

After the line:

```
$this->_redirectUrl($url);
```

I added:

```
$message = $this->__('You have successfully logged in.');
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess($message);
```

Answer (score 1):

I just implemented this and it worked. But other links to the dashboard are still working.

For this case I used a url rewrite set in the backend (catalog > url rewrites)

I used a customized redirect from `customer/account` to `sales/order/history` in order to forward from the dashboard to the order overview. Nice and clean without adding additional code